# PS Script to switch between layers in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-scripting, shortcuts, script

I've been searching for months for a solution to use a `shortcut` to select the one **layer above** the selected or the **layer underneath** the selected one.

Because I dodge & burn with curves it's taking ages otherwise, And yes I know about the 50% grey layer ;)

If you have any idea, I know there was a **script** online called **ToggleDBLayers** but it's not online any more.

Happy for help!

Michael

Comment: It's already there, you don't need a script. Alt [ or ] from  Adobe's help pages - https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/default-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: @Tetsujin its just that many locales cant use that shortcut

Comment: On my fin/swe keyboard I need to hold down `Shift` and press 8 or 9 to make either `[` or `]`. The only way I can use this shortcut is by switching to US keyboard layout in OS and press whichever key has `[` and `]` according to the US layout... Or by using a script: [some layer selection scripts](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-layer-selection-scripts) that have been made using the Scripting listener. — For some reason some shortcuts can't be changed and these two happen to be one of those.

Comment: Questions about differing locales need to mention such - many times the position stays the same, but the resulting command is a 'different letter'

Comment: The shortcut works on my UK keyboard layout. For others is it not just a matter of holding down Alt + either Shift or AltGr if it's located on another key?

Comment: To the OP. Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/152579/edit) and tell us what keyboard layout you are using?  Thanks.

Comment: I have two keyboard layouts instaled, one in Portuguese and another in English to perform some shortcuts like 'hold tilde key'. I just press Windows+SpaceBar to toggle between them. In my opinion, it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also use the two curve d&b setup and share the same frustrations as the OP. In my case, I don't have the keyboard issues, so in theory I could use the built in shortcuts however the need for multiple keys is clunky and I'm I'm also running out of space on my keyboard.

PhotoshopChef makes a d&b plugin that will generate the layers to your own specs, then you can double tap the X key to toggle between the layers. It works well.